# spring + hibernate + c3p0 + ehcache java configuration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, ehcache, c3p0

I am new to spring, hibernate, c3p0 & ehcache. I am developing an application completely using Java Configuration except web.xml. I have to use second level cache in my app. So I added following code

```
import net.sf.ehcache.config.CacheConfiguration;

import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.CachingConfigurer;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheErrorHandler;
import org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheResolver;
import org.springframework.cache.interceptor.KeyGenerator;
import org.springframework.cache.interceptor.SimpleKeyGenerator;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CachingConfig implements CachingConfigurer{

    @Bean(destroyMethod="shutdown")
    public net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager ehCacheManager() {
        CacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration = new CacheConfiguration();
        cacheConfiguration.setName("myCacheName");
        cacheConfiguration.setMemoryStoreEvictionPolicy("LRU");
        cacheConfiguration.setMaxEntriesLocalHeap(1000);

        net.sf.ehcache.config.Configuration config = new net.sf.ehcache.config.Configuration();
        config.addCache(cacheConfiguration);

        return net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.newInstance(config);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return new EhCacheCacheManager(ehCacheManager());
    }

    @Override
    public CacheResolver cacheResolver() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public CacheErrorHandler errorHandler() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public KeyGenerator keyGenerator() {
        return new SimpleKeyGenerator();
    }

}
```

In web.xml I added it as

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        ApplicationContextConfiguration
        CachingConfig
    </param-value>
  </context-param>
```

My ApplicationContextConfiguration is

```
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource;


@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ApplicationContextConfiguration 
{
       @Bean
       public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws IOException {
          LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
          entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(pooledDataSource());
          entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "*" });      
          JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
          entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
          entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());     
          return entityManagerFactory;
       }

       @Bean
       public ComboPooledDataSource pooledDataSource() throws IOException{
          ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
          Properties properties = new Properties();

          BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (getClass().getResourceAsStream("/config/hibernate.properties")));
          properties.load(input);
          try {
              dataSource.setDriverClass(properties.getProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class"));
          } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          dataSource.setJdbcUrl(properties.getProperty("hibernate.connection.url"));
          dataSource.setUser(properties.getProperty("hibernate.connection.username"));
          dataSource.setPassword(properties.getProperty("hibernate.connection.password"));

          dataSource.setMaxPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_size")));
          dataSource.setMinPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("hibernate.c3p0.min_size")));
          dataSource.setCheckoutTimeout(Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("hibernate.c3p0.timeout")));
          dataSource.setMaxStatements(Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_statements")));
          dataSource.setIdleConnectionTestPeriod(Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period")));
          dataSource.setAcquireIncrement(Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment")));

          return dataSource;
       }

       @Bean
       public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
          return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
       }

       Properties additionalProperties() throws IOException {
          Properties properties = new Properties();
          Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();          
          BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (getClass().getResourceAsStream("/config/hibernate.properties")));                 
          hibernateProperties.load(input);        
          properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", hibernateProperties.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
          return properties;
       }

}
```

When I try to run I am getting following error

```
org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheRegionFactoryAvailableException: Second-level cache is used in the application, but property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class is not given, please either disable second level cache or set correct region factory class name to property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class (and make sure the second level cache provider, hibernate-infinispan, for example, is available in the classpath).
```

I understood that I have to add

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
```

but not sure where and how to add it via Java configuration. Can someone help here please.

In addition, do I need to add the following?

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
```

Comment: Is you application currently running with out second level cache? I mean are you able to save and retrieve the entities without second level cache? And why do you want to use `CachingConfigurer`? because that has nothing to do with Hibernate second level cache that you are referring to?

Comment: @Madhusudana Reddy Sunnapu -- yea I am able to retrieve without second level cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are able to retrieve the entities and you just want to enable second level cache:

Add following properties in your existing `additionalProperties()` method.

```
properties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory");
properties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "true");
properties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", "true");
```

and on the `entity` you want to enable second level cache place `@Cache` annotation on that entity ex: `@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)`

You can remove `CachingConfig` class as that has nothing to do with enabling second level cache for Hibernate.