# Long delay in server startup time

Tags: spring, hibernate, jersey, tomcat7

Developing Web Services using Spring, Hibernate and Jersey in parallel to an existing application. Initially I was using less than 20 entity classes and server took less than 45 seconds to start. Now I added all 191 entity classes which I will need later point of time. After adding those my application is taking almost 7 minutes to start. By the way I am using Tomcat 7 as my server.

In logs I can see lot of

```
o.h.ejb.packaging.AbstractJarVisitor - Filtering:............

o.h.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder - Collection role:.......
o.h.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder - Building property.......
org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column - Binding column: Ejb3JoinColumn{....
org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column - Binding column: Ejb3Column{table.....

o.h.c.annotations.SimpleValueBinder - Setting SimpleValue typeName for .....

o.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass - Second pass for collection:......
o.h.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder - Binding a OneToMany: .....
o.h.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder - Mapping collection: .....
o.h.cfg.annotations.TableBinder - Retrieving property ......

org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Resolving reference to class: .....

o.h.c.e.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [.....]; using defaults.
net.sf.ehcache.Cache - Initialised cache: .....
n.s.e.config.ConfigurationHelper - CacheDecoratorFactory not configured for defaultCache. Skipping for '.....
o.h.c.e.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - started EHCache region:....
o.h.p.entity.AbstractEntityPersister - Static SQL for entity:.....
o.h.p.entity.AbstractEntityPersister -  Version select: .....
o.h.p.entity.AbstractEntityPersister -  Snapshot select:....
o.h.p.entity.AbstractEntityPersister -  Insert 0: .....
o.h.p.entity.AbstractEntityPersister -  Update 0: ....
o.h.p.entity.AbstractEntityPersister -  Delete 0: ....

o.h.p.c.AbstractCollectionPersister - Static SQL for collection:.....
o.h.p.c.AbstractCollectionPersister -  Row insert: .....
o.h.p.c.AbstractCollectionPersister -  Row update: .....
o.h.p.c.AbstractCollectionPersister -  Row delete: .....
o.h.p.c.AbstractCollectionPersister -  One-shot delete: ....
```

I observed the following is taking lot of time

```
org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Static select for entity ... [NONE]: ...
org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Static select for entity ... [READ]: ...
org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Static select for entity ... [UPGRADE]: ...
org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Static select for entity ... [UPGRADE_NOWAIT]: ...
org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Static select for entity ... [FORCE]: ...
org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Static select for entity ... [PESSIMISTIC_READ]: ...
org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Static select for entity ... [PESSIMISTIC_WRITE]: ...
org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Static select for entity ... [PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT]: ...
org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Static select for entity ... [OPTIMISTIC]: ...
org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Static select for entity ... [OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT]: ...
org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Static select for action ACTION_MERGE on entity ... : ...
org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Static select for action ACTION_REFRESH on entity ...: ...

o.h.l.collection.OneToManyLoader - Static select for one-to-many
```

How to improve startup time?

Note: using Spring version:4.1.4.RELEASE, 
      Hibernate version: 4.2.7.Final

I am using java config and you can see my java config at [spring + hibernate + c3p0 + ehcache java configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36304458/spring-hibernate-c3p0-ehcache-java-configuration/36305748). Not using separate persistence.xml

Comment: Looking at the logs it seems there are some deletes, updates and inserts happening during the start up. If so, can you provide some information on what the app is doing during the start up? Also posting your persistence.xml file might help.

Comment: For starters disable logging as logging is slow and really slows down startup of your application.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu I am using java config and you can see my java config at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36304458/spring-hibernate-c3p0-ehcache-java-configuration/36305748. Not using separate persistence.xml. More over I haven't configured anything at startup time.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this properties in your persistence unit configuration, inside `persistence.xml`:

```
<property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" value="false"/>
```

It usually speeds up Hibernate.

2016-04-14 Appended an "s" to correct the property name.

Comment: Already tried like that there is no improvement. You can see my config at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36304458/spring-hibernate-c3p0-ehcache-java-configuration/36305748.

Comment: in additionalProperties method I added code like properties.setProperty("hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults","false");

Comment: Are you using 'org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider' as provider right? Also post your hibernate configuration class/file

Comment: As you can see in my config there is not specific hibernate config class/file. I am setting all those via pooledDataSource() method.

Comment: initially I am not using 'org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider'. So added code in config as 'entityManagerFactory.setPersistenceProviderClass(org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);'

Comment: after adding the code added some jars in POM for hibernate-entitymanager(4.3.5.Final). Which I used same version for hibernate-ehcache, hibernate-c3p0, hibernate-core. Also corrected my hibernate-jpa-2.1-api(1.0.0.Final). Now the code it is taking lot of time and in logs I see 'o.h.p.w.spi.MetamodelGraphWalker - Visiting attribute path ....'